# Graph Algorithm addVertex key as a string

Tags: algorithm, graph

This is a Graph. When I addVertex by passing in a parameter without a space, it returns a key as a string. See below:
I was expecting Hong Kong instead of "Hong Kong"

```js
Graph {
  adjacencyList: {
    Tokyo: [ 'Singapore' ],
    Singapore: [ 'Tokyo', 'Malaysia', 'Hong Kong' ],
    Malaysia: [ 'Singapore' ],
    'Hong Kong': [ 'Singapore', 'Australia' ],
    Australia: [ 'Hong Kong' ]
  }
}
```

```js
class Graph {
    constructor() {
        this.adjacencyList = {}
    }

    addVertex(vertex) {
        if (!this.adjacencyList[vertex]) {
            this.adjacencyList[vertex] = []
        }
    }

    addEdge(vertex1, vertex2) {
        if (this.adjacencyList[vertex1]) {
            this.adjacencyList[vertex1].push(vertex2)
        }
        if (this.adjacencyList[vertex2]) {
            this.adjacencyList[vertex2].push(vertex1)
        }
    }
}

let g = new Graph()
g.addVertex("Tokyo")
g.addVertex("Singapore")
g.addVertex("Malaysia")
g.addVertex("Hong Kong")
g.addVertex("Australia")
g.addEdge("Tokyo", "Singapore")
g.addEdge("Singapore", "Malaysia")
g.addEdge("Singapore", "Hong Kong")
g.addEdge("Hong Kong", "Australia")
console.log(g)
```

Comment: You should also precise what language this is, this is strongly related to that. (I suspect javascript ?)

Comment: Hi yes, this is JavaScript! Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then add the tag, it really helps for future reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference you see is only a difference in how the browser choose to print the key : [all key in javascript are strings](https://www.becomebetterprogrammer.com/can-javasscript-object-keys-be-numbers-or-non-string-values/)

It's just that when the string is in one word, it's prettier to not show the `"` around it, but when it's in multiple words it could be confusing not to.

You can check that by using `console.log(g.adjacencyList['Tokyo'])`